# compatibility between the same table fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got shop types. Some shop types doesn't compatible with other shop types (for example you can't sell car parts near food for example).

Here is my table schema:

```
create table TShopCompatibility
(
idshoptype1 int NOT NULL,
idshoptype2 int NOT NULL,
constraint pkSHOPCOMP primary key(idshoptype1,idshoptype2),
constraint fkSHOPCOMP1 foreign key(idshoptype1) references TShopType(idshoptype),
constraint fkSHOPCOMP2 foreign key(idshoptype2) references TShopType(idshoptype),
constraint cSHOPCOMP12 check(idshoptype1>idshoptype2)
)
```

I've got these values:

```
2 - 1
3  - 1
5  - 1
5  - 2
10  - 9
12  - 11
13  - 10
```

How where id - shoptypes. How can I get what shops are compatible for example with idshoptype = 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to select the shop types where `2` is present in idshoptype1 or idshoptype2, i.e.

```
SELECT idshoptype1 FROM TShopCompatibility WHERE idshoptype2 = 2
UNION
SELECT idshoptype2 FROM TShopCompatibility WHERE idshoptype1 = 2
```

Then you can join the result of this query with shops table to get the shop information.